# In python while using pack it is truncating my MSB bits while packing a long variable,

Tags: python, python-packaging

```
    int1 = 11111111
    int2 = 22222222
    long1 = 6666666666666666   
    int3 = 33333333
    int4 = 44444444
    int5 = 55555555
    pack_list = (int1,int2,long1,int3,int4,int5)     
    pack_format = struct.Struct('> I I L I I I')              
    pack_data = pack_format.pack(*pack_list)   

    print "Original_values:", pack_list    
    print "Format_string:", pack_format.format     
    print "Uses:", pack_format.size,'bytes'   
    print "Packed_value:", binascii.hexlify(pack_data)
```

I have 64 bits in a long variable but when I pack using big-endian it is treating it as an integer which you can see in the output showing as 24 bytes instead of 28 bytes which is the actual length of the data. Can someone tell me what is going on and help me to get all 64 bits in big-endian packed data

> > > > Original Values: (11111111, 22222222, 66666666, 33333333, 44444444, 55555555)
> > > >         Format_string: > I I L I I I
> > > >         Uses: 24 bytes
> > > >         Packed_value: 111111112222222266666666333333334444444455555555

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This should raise an exception in 2.7 and 3.x, not silently truncate.

Comment: Anyway, for 64-bit int, you want format `Q`, not `L`.

Comment: Great It works, you saved my day. Thank you very much

Comment: but in the documentation I saw it as an L what does the Q stands for

Comment: @PhanendraNath: Presumably "quadword" (by the old nomenclature for 16 bit x86, where 16 bits was a word, 32 was a doubleword/dword, and while it didn't exist back then, 64 bits was later described as a quadword following the same pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifier `L` means a C `long`, which is generally 32 bits—the same size as a C `int`. So your 64-bit number is too large to fit. (I’m pretty sure Python 2.7 and 3.x are supposed to give you an OverflowError or ValueError or something rather than silently truncating… but at any rate, it’s not going to work.)

The format specifier `Q` means a C `long long`, which is generally 64 bits, so that’s the one you want.

In case you’re wondering why Python has both I and L when they mean the same thing—well, it’s really just because C has both int and long, but there is, or at least used to be, a reason for that. Nowadays, int is almost always 32 bits, but back when Python was originally written, it was usually whichever of 16 or 32 bits was faster on your platform. So, if you were trying to match a struct from some Unix API defined to use int, you had to use I; a struct defined to use long, you had to use L; mix them up and your code wouldn’t be portable between different systems.

And if you’re wondering why `q` is short for `long long`—it’s really short for “quad”, at least indirectly. Most likely, it comes from a variety of different Unix systems using `q` as the `printf` format specifier prefix for their nonstandard 64-bit types (so `%qd` means a 64-bit int printed as a decimal number). If not, it probably comes from Windows using `QWORD` for a 64-bit struct of two 32-bit ints. In both cases, the “q” meant “quad”—16 bits is a word, 32 bits is a double word, and 64 bits is a quad(ruple) word. (In the `printf` case, it may also be relevant that there were only so many single letter prefixes to go around. Later, the C and POSIX standards got around that by just allowing multi-letter prefixes, so it’s now `%lld`, which *is* short for `long long`.)